# How to import a nested object .JSON file of this format?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to import the data from this JSON file to work with it in my python script. However, I am receiving the following error, I believe due to the nested nature of the JSON objects. My final goal is to collect the file name, and labels for each JSON object. I do not care about having duplicates, similarly to the current format of the .JSON file.

```
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    big_json_file = json.loads(file_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Below is the python script "test.py":

```
import json

file_string = 'output.json'
big_json_file = json.loads(file_string)
big_list_of_labels = []

for file in big_json_file:
    big_list_of_labels.append(file['Analysis']['Labels'])
```

Below is the .JSON file that I am attempting to import:

```json
[
   {
      "File_Name": "1.jpg",
      "Analysis": {
         "Labels": [
            {
               "Confidence": 94.77251434326172,
               "Name": "Flora"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 94.77251434326172,
               "Name": "Grass"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 94.77251434326172,
               "Name": "Plant"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 78.49254608154297,
               "Name": "Animal"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 78.49254608154297,
               "Name": "Cheetah"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 78.49254608154297,
               "Name": "Mammal"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 78.49254608154297,
               "Name": "Wildlife"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 69.79740142822266,
               "Name": "Field"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 69.79740142822266,
               "Name": "Grassland"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 69.79740142822266,
               "Name": "Outdoors"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 67.31356048583984,
               "Name": "Leisure Activities"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 67.31356048583984,
               "Name": "Walking"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 57.44683837890625,
               "Name": "Jaguar"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 57.44683837890625,
               "Name": "Leopard"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 57.44683837890625,
               "Name": "Panther"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 55.88261032104492,
               "Name": "Bush"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 55.88261032104492,
               "Name": "Vegetation"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 53.4413948059082,
               "Name": "Lawn"
            }
         ],
         "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RetryAttempts": 0,
            "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
            "RequestId": "978e32e4-1da8-11e8-a380-cd680f89684e",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
               "date": "Thu, 01 Mar 2018 23:30:59 GMT",
               "x-amzn-requestid": "978e32e4-1da8-11e8-a380-cd680f89684e",
               "content-length": "947",
               "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
               "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
         },
         "OrientationCorrection": "ROTATE_0"
      }
   }
][
   {
      "File_Name": "2.jpg",
      "Analysis": {
         "Labels": [
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Astronomy"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Galaxy"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Nebula"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Night"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Outdoors"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Outer Space"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Space"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Universe"
            }
         ],
         "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RetryAttempts": 0,
            "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
            "RequestId": "98d2c109-1da8-11e8-a2d9-b91cf22c7f33",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
               "date": "Thu, 01 Mar 2018 23:30:59 GMT",
               "x-amzn-requestid": "98d2c109-1da8-11e8-a2d9-b91cf22c7f33",
               "content-length": "449",
               "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
               "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
         },
         "OrientationCorrection": "ROTATE_0"
      }
   },
   {
      "File_Name": "2.jpg",
      "Analysis": {
         "Labels": [
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Astronomy"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Galaxy"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Nebula"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Night"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Outdoors"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Outer Space"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Space"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Universe"
            }
         ],
         "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RetryAttempts": 0,
            "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
            "RequestId": "98d2c109-1da8-11e8-a2d9-b91cf22c7f33",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
               "date": "Thu, 01 Mar 2018 23:30:59 GMT",
               "x-amzn-requestid": "98d2c109-1da8-11e8-a2d9-b91cf22c7f33",
               "content-length": "449",
               "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
               "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
         },
         "OrientationCorrection": "ROTATE_0"
      }
   }
][
   {
      "File_Name": "3.jpg",
      "Analysis": {
         "Labels": [
            {
               "Confidence": 98.6434555053711,
               "Name": "Human"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.6434097290039,
               "Name": "People"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.6434555053711,
               "Name": "Person"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 96.43375396728516,
               "Name": "Audience"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 96.43375396728516,
               "Name": "Crowd"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 96.43375396728516,
               "Name": "Speech"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Badge"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Emblem"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Logo"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Trademark"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 59.94097137451172,
               "Name": "Worker"
            }
         ],
         "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RetryAttempts": 0,
            "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
            "RequestId": "99394a95-1da8-11e8-876f-6db2ab84a252",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
               "date": "Thu, 01 Mar 2018 23:30:59 GMT",
               "x-amzn-requestid": "99394a95-1da8-11e8-876f-6db2ab84a252",
               "content-length": "583",
               "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
               "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
         },
         "OrientationCorrection": "ROTATE_0"
      }
   },
   {
      "File_Name": "3.jpg",
      "Analysis": {
         "Labels": [
            {
               "Confidence": 98.6434555053711,
               "Name": "Human"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.6434097290039,
               "Name": "People"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.6434555053711,
               "Name": "Person"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 96.43375396728516,
               "Name": "Audience"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 96.43375396728516,
               "Name": "Crowd"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 96.43375396728516,
               "Name": "Speech"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Badge"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Emblem"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Logo"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Trademark"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 59.94097137451172,
               "Name": "Worker"
            }
         ],
         "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RetryAttempts": 0,
            "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
            "RequestId": "99394a95-1da8-11e8-876f-6db2ab84a252",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
               "date": "Thu, 01 Mar 2018 23:30:59 GMT",
               "x-amzn-requestid": "99394a95-1da8-11e8-876f-6db2ab84a252",
               "content-length": "583",
               "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
               "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
         },
         "OrientationCorrection": "ROTATE_0"
      }
   },
   {
      "File_Name": "3.jpg",
      "Analysis": {
         "Labels": [
            {
               "Confidence": 98.6434555053711,
               "Name": "Human"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.6434097290039,
               "Name": "People"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.6434555053711,
               "Name": "Person"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 96.43375396728516,
               "Name": "Audience"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 96.43375396728516,
               "Name": "Crowd"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 96.43375396728516,
               "Name": "Speech"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Badge"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Emblem"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Logo"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 80.42803192138672,
               "Name": "Trademark"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 59.94097137451172,
               "Name": "Worker"
            }
         ],
         "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RetryAttempts": 0,
            "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
            "RequestId": "99394a95-1da8-11e8-876f-6db2ab84a252",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
               "date": "Thu, 01 Mar 2018 23:30:59 GMT",
               "x-amzn-requestid": "99394a95-1da8-11e8-876f-6db2ab84a252",
               "content-length": "583",
               "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
               "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
         },
         "OrientationCorrection": "ROTATE_0"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: what you put is not a single json object but multiple json obj, use https://jsonlint.com/ to quick check you have a valid json

Comment: @ZhouQuan an array is a valid json object.  Try `json.loads('["a", "b", "c"]')` and you'll find out it works as expected. The problem here is that the op passes a file name (`"output.json"`) to `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 4):

So the problem is that the json.loads expect the actual json(string) to be passed, not a filename. You can open a file with `with` an use the filepointer in json.load like this.

```
import json

with open('output.json') as thefile:
    big_json_file = json.load(thefile)
    big_list_of_labels = []

    for file in big_json_file:
        big_list_of_labels.append(file['Analysis']['Labels'])
```

Also, your json is invalid.. needs a `,` instead of `][` in two places.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps reading the doc could help ?

> `json.loads(s, *, encoding=None, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw)`
>
> Deserialize s (a str, bytes or bytearray instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object

And there's an example a couple lines above:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
['foo', {'bar': ['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

In your snippet here:

```
file_string = 'output.json'
big_json_file = json.loads(file_string)
```

The literal string `"output.json"` is obviously not a JSON document. It may be the name of a file containing a json document but that's not what `json.loads()` expects (cf the example).

What you want it to read the file's content and pass it to `json.loads()`:

```
with open ("output.json") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
print(data)
```

Which can be further simplified using `json.load()` (no 's') which takes an opened file as argument instead:

```
with open ("output.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(data)
```